# Read Excel Content After Uploading File in MVC And Fill Some Textboxes

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

I'm uploading an excel file and want to read file content and with jquery ajax fill some textboxes with excel content after uploading.
the file uploading correctly but I have Problem when I want read excel content.
can anybody help me?

```
public JsonResult ImportExcelToTextBoxes()
{
    try
    {
        var ExcelFile = Request.Files[0];

        if (ExcelFile != null && ExcelFile.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            //// .xlsx
            //IExcelDataReader reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(ExcelFile.InputStream);

            // .xls
            IExcelDataReader reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(ExcelFile.InputStream);

            var result = reader.AsDataSet(new ExcelDataSetConfiguration() {
                ConfigureDataTable = (_) => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration() {
                    UseHeaderRow = true
                }
            });
        }

        //foreach (var item in ExcelFile)
        {
        IList lst = new List<ET.Reservation.Classes.PassengerSaleSeat>();
        ET.Reservation.Classes.PassengerSaleSeat pass = new ET.Reservation.Classes.PassengerSaleSeat();
        pass.FirstName = "testtt";//this section is for test
        pass.LastName = "tttttt";//this section is for test
        pass.Gender = ET.Public.Enumerations.GENDER.Female;//this section is for test
        lst.Add(pass);//this section is for test
        }

        return Json(lst);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
        throw ex;
    }
    return null;
}
```

**and js section:**

```
$('#btnUploadExcel').click(function () {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', fileInput.files[0]);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/PassengerSaleSeat/ImportExcelToDatabase",
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                alert(data[i].FirstName);
            }
        },
        error: function(err) {
            alert('error');
        }

    });
});
```

**and input is:**

```
<input id="fileInput" type="file">
<button type="button" id="btnUploadExcel" class="btn btn-labeled btn btn-success">Send</button>
```

**JSON Return:**
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oflon.png)

Comment: any error on browser console?

Comment: "I have problem when I want read excel content" - can you explain in detail what problem you currently have? Are you getting error message or exception?

Comment: @ArunKumar 
there is no error in browser.I want almost a solution or idea for this

Comment: @mohammadfarokhian Can you show us the returned JSON in success function?

Comment: @ArunKumar
yes JSON is success .but I am confused about read excel content after upload

Comment: Can you show the JSON?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto
after uploading my excel file I have no Idea that how can read excel content(row and columns).after find this solution,I want fill some textboxes on my page from excel content

Comment: @ArunKumar
how can I Show?

Comment: Just add in your question

Comment: @ArunKumar
image added

Comment: Just debug your ajax success function and then add image of your response which you are getting in `data`

Comment: @ArunKumar
Is this what you need?

Comment: add `console.log(data)` in your ajax success function like `success: function (data) {console.log(data)` and then check browser console what's there.

Comment: @ArunKumar
this is not what I want.
JSON is working right.
my problem is found out a way to read my uploaded file(excel) and fill boxes from excel information

Comment: Yes I got that but for that you need to correctly map the returned json to your elements on page. That's why I was asking for your JSON structure

Comment: @ArunKumar you want to need JSON function is true or false?
JSON returned true function